# Why does d3 line plot not work for custom sorted time labels?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I sorted TIME column of my data so that it starts from 12:00:00, to 00:00:00, and ends at 11:59:59. However, line plot does not reflect well this range when I choose the range of domain of xAxis from 12:00:00 to 11:59:59, and no line is shown.

**WHat I have (x-axis):** when I choose the range of domain of xAxis from 12:00:00 to 11:59:59:
[image]

**What I expect (x-axis):** when I choose the range of domain of xAxis from 12:00:00 to 11:59:59:
[image]

How can I obtain such x-axis?

PS:*The code below draws line in PyCharm, however, line is not showing neither in SO code line, nor in JSFiddle. I would appreciate if you point my mistake out here.*

```js
data = [
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 12:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "12",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 82.4818356370727,
    "VALUE2": "87.65532538616083",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T11:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "720"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 12:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "12",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 114.36084687826856,
    "VALUE2": "89.76606638044296",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T11:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "740"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 12:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "12",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 149.2745234585085,
    "VALUE2": "78.59914264907545",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T11:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "760"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 13:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "13",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 118.46198153923852,
    "VALUE2": "71.602023294704",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T12:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "780"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 13:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "13",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 113.47363946789812,
    "VALUE2": "82.9802315554754",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T12:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "800"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 13:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "13",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 124.52765200932272,
    "VALUE2": "79.25241460867473",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T12:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "820"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 14:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "14",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 144.94079558959947,
    "VALUE2": "65.9708531211893",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T13:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "840"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 14:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "14",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 154.4860403982185,
    "VALUE2": "62.47993589006475",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T13:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "860"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 14:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "14",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 103.05095426442168,
    "VALUE2": "79.12278561261758",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T13:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "880"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 15:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "15",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 88.71000005665377,
    "VALUE2": "72.63269391153845",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T14:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "900"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 15:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "15",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 118.38725463585833,
    "VALUE2": "68.35955256035255",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T14:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "920"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 15:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "15",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 90.35575706090954,
    "VALUE2": "84.996720275759",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T14:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "940"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 16:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "16",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 119.53679642856682,
    "VALUE2": "64.48688419793011",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T15:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "960"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 16:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "16",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 135.27829999848916,
    "VALUE2": "74.48257447199506",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T15:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "980"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 16:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "16",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 155.48291761113225,
    "VALUE2": "83.72128851838752",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T15:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1000"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 17:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "17",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 85.96341780030743,
    "VALUE2": "87.73333389566491",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1020"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 17:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "17",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 148.20928658532694,
    "VALUE2": "68.51872403107251",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T16:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1040"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 17:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "17",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 112.90401161612893,
    "VALUE2": "78.71422067548829",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T16:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1060"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 18:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "18",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 87.24314271333824,
    "VALUE2": "85.14578512967933",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T17:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1080"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 18:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "18",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 159.98777892013288,
    "VALUE2": "73.91122953488058",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T17:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1100"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 18:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "18",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 134.132508027465,
    "VALUE2": "62.87714757838526",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T17:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1120"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 19:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "19",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 93.8475785922444,
    "VALUE2": "85.87709920539899",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T18:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1140"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 19:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "19",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 87.96494807670916,
    "VALUE2": "64.32810207816041",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T18:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1160"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 19:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "19",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 96.85350185792925,
    "VALUE2": "87.67564666896372",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T18:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1180"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 20:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "20",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 150.49329018102594,
    "VALUE2": "75.28292350135503",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T19:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1200"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 20:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "20",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 132.90939839406852,
    "VALUE2": "67.6641419034086",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T19:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1220"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 20:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "20",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 80.28565707426297,
    "VALUE2": "54.21677488141204",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T19:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1240"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 21:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "21",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 86.51819145398362,
    "VALUE2": "76.47547776446376",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T20:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1260"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 21:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "21",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 100.58643623741963,
    "VALUE2": "54.02216986378453",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T20:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1280"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 21:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "21",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 109.88077988150214,
    "VALUE2": "88.83099789311015",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T20:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1300"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 22:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "22",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 133.64148337171653,
    "VALUE2": "86.82795237554191",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T21:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1320"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 22:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "22",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 141.1790901060669,
    "VALUE2": "55.91956277329068",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T21:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1340"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 22:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "22",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 106.49414930906852,
    "VALUE2": "74.54271614590431",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T21:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1360"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 23:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "23",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 140.44553457410672,
    "VALUE2": "78.3447955131424",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T22:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1380"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 23:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "23",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 102.26703222395386,
    "VALUE2": "54.51054689408265",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T22:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1400"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 23:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "23",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 138.07031707200693,
    "VALUE2": "80.52691368274375",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T22:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1420"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 00:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "0",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 131.8403388480975,
    "VALUE2": "163.40706930229612",
    "TIME": "1899-12-31T23:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "0"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 00:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "0",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 128.66143180880016,
    "VALUE2": "182.4166850946821",
    "TIME": "1899-12-31T23:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "20"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 00:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "0",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 157.9838672230082,
    "VALUE2": "177.12826879097582",
    "TIME": "1899-12-31T23:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "40"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 01:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "1",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 154.74491894762372,
    "VALUE2": "177.0205615343229",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "60"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 01:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "1",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 145.17425322202857,
    "VALUE2": "170.28572211898427",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T00:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "80"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 01:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "1",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 86.33692934233684,
    "VALUE2": "161.306233500133",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T00:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "100"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 02:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "2",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 157.70472270832147,
    "VALUE2": "175.57007397898963",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T01:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "120"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 02:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "2",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 92.04378773072384,
    "VALUE2": "152.75885569609832",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T01:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "140"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 02:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "2",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 94.91482763887927,
    "VALUE2": "164.34713115356462",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T01:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "160"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 03:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "3",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 150.58752716935703,
    "VALUE2": "152.5739950034875",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T02:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "180"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 03:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "3",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 147.64763286003245,
    "VALUE2": "181.7346317353725",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T02:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "200"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 03:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "3",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 152.00311766772614,
    "VALUE2": "169.43438782829136",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T02:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "220"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 04:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "4",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 90.67568616871652,
    "VALUE2": "165.94364405219295",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T03:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "240"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 04:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "4",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 127.6260776280666,
    "VALUE2": "154.41327889693227",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T03:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "260"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 04:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "4",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 88.35193693321801,
    "VALUE2": "86.7514997924824",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T03:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "280"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 05:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "5",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 99.44723697225662,
    "VALUE2": "61.81705113015809",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T04:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "300"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 05:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "5",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 153.28490595395064,
    "VALUE2": "70.71671056760238",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T04:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "320"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 05:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "5",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 139.53124376248127,
    "VALUE2": "86.96902617467873",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T04:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "340"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 06:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "6",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 144.5960580946409,
    "VALUE2": "53.46091762212306",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T05:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "360"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 06:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "6",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 110.0561197803852,
    "VALUE2": "73.32550566412914",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T05:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "380"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 06:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "6",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 151.21482961729612,
    "VALUE2": "50.85883825605632",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T05:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "400"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 07:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "7",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 127.88766918064591,
    "VALUE2": "52.45266678876003",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T06:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "420"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 07:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "7",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 148.72830141013,
    "VALUE2": "60.496196118302194",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T06:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "440"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 07:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "7",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 83.62908148257569,
    "VALUE2": "86.54612924908034",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T06:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "460"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 08:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "8",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 113.49475177931872,
    "VALUE2": "59.15439348393694",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T07:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "480"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 08:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "8",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 139.37377082538475,
    "VALUE2": "86.1347823168292",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T07:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "500"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 08:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "8",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 104.5216263376223,
    "VALUE2": "86.92624219265554",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T07:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "520"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 09:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "9",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 152.55680056900144,
    "VALUE2": "60.938994790632144",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T08:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "540"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 09:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "9",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 140.38896796205978,
    "VALUE2": "56.19504976107255",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T08:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "560"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 09:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "9",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 135.79579769996857,
    "VALUE2": "62.50941443441722",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T08:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "580"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 10:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "10",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 139.82904911416367,
    "VALUE2": "55.70678841865249",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T09:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "600"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 10:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "10",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 91.69787531743796,
    "VALUE2": "60.136426910820354",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T09:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "620"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 10:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "10",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 96.81085932421924,
    "VALUE2": "80.24824051838286",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T09:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "640"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 11:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "11",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 100.11254271252508,
    "VALUE2": "60.56291710797137",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T10:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "660"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 11:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "11",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 92.56760281588778,
    "VALUE2": "71.09234847495347",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T10:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "680"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 11:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "11",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 100.3186503333999,
    "VALUE2": "72.55516506446128",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T10:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "700"
  }
]

// Set up the SVG container
const svgWidth = 600;
const svgHeight = 400;
const margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 50 };
const chartWidth = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
const chartHeight = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight);

const chart = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);
  
  

// Parse the date string and extract only the time as hours and minutes
      const parseTime = d3.timeParse("%H:%M:%S");

      // Convert data types
      data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.TIME = parseTime(d.TIME);
        d.VALUE1 = +d.VALUE1;
        d.INSPECTION = +d.INSPECTION;
      });

      let visit1 = data.filter(d => d.INSPECTION === 1);
      // console.log(visit1)
      // Set up scales
      const xScale = d3
        .scaleTime()
        .domain([parseTime("12:00:00"), parseTime("23:59:00")]) // Adjusted the domain to end at 11:59 AM
        .range([0, chartWidth]);

      const yScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 180])
        .range([chartHeight, 0]);

      // Set up axes
      const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
        .ticks(d3.timeHour.every(1)) // Display tick labels every 1 hour
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M"));

      const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

      // Add axes to the chart
      chart
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "x-axis")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${chartHeight})`)
        .call(xAxis);

      chart.append("g").attr("class", "y-axis").call(yAxis);

      // Define the line function
      const line = d3
        .line()
        .x((d) => xScale(d.TIME))
        .y((d) => yScale(d.VALUE1));

      // Draw the line chart
      chart
        .append("path")
        .datum(visit1)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>D3 CSV Example</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* LINE CHART */
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ed3700;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>D3 CSV Example</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ajusted your date parser to match your data `TIME` format

`const const parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ")`

And your domain to match the time parser

`.domain([parseTime("1900-01-01T12:00:00.000Z"), parseTime("1900-01-01T23:59:00.000Z")])`

With the sort you don't have the horizontal line anymore

`data.sort((a,b)=>a.TIME-b.TIME)`

If you want to plot all your data you can change xScale domain to :
`.domain(d3.extent(visit1.map(d=>d.TIME)))`

```js
data = [
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 12:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "12",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 82.4818356370727,
    "VALUE2": "87.65532538616083",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T11:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "720"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 12:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "12",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 114.36084687826856,
    "VALUE2": "89.76606638044296",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T11:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "740"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 12:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "12",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 149.2745234585085,
    "VALUE2": "78.59914264907545",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T11:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "760"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 13:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "13",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 118.46198153923852,
    "VALUE2": "71.602023294704",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T12:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "780"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 13:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "13",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 113.47363946789812,
    "VALUE2": "82.9802315554754",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T12:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "800"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 13:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "13",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 124.52765200932272,
    "VALUE2": "79.25241460867473",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T12:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "820"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 14:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "14",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 144.94079558959947,
    "VALUE2": "65.9708531211893",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T13:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "840"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 14:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "14",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 154.4860403982185,
    "VALUE2": "62.47993589006475",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T13:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "860"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 14:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "14",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 103.05095426442168,
    "VALUE2": "79.12278561261758",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T13:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "880"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 15:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "15",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 88.71000005665377,
    "VALUE2": "72.63269391153845",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T14:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "900"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 15:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "15",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 118.38725463585833,
    "VALUE2": "68.35955256035255",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T14:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "920"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 15:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "15",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 90.35575706090954,
    "VALUE2": "84.996720275759",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T14:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "940"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 16:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "16",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 119.53679642856682,
    "VALUE2": "64.48688419793011",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T15:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "960"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 16:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "16",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 135.27829999848916,
    "VALUE2": "74.48257447199506",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T15:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "980"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 16:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "16",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 155.48291761113225,
    "VALUE2": "83.72128851838752",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T15:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1000"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 17:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "17",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 85.96341780030743,
    "VALUE2": "87.73333389566491",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1020"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 17:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "17",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 148.20928658532694,
    "VALUE2": "68.51872403107251",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T16:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1040"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 17:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "17",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 112.90401161612893,
    "VALUE2": "78.71422067548829",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T16:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1060"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 18:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "18",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 87.24314271333824,
    "VALUE2": "85.14578512967933",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T17:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1080"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 18:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "18",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 159.98777892013288,
    "VALUE2": "73.91122953488058",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T17:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1100"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 18:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "18",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 134.132508027465,
    "VALUE2": "62.87714757838526",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T17:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1120"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 19:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "19",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 93.8475785922444,
    "VALUE2": "85.87709920539899",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T18:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1140"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 19:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "19",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 87.96494807670916,
    "VALUE2": "64.32810207816041",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T18:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1160"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 19:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "19",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 96.85350185792925,
    "VALUE2": "87.67564666896372",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T18:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1180"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 20:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "20",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 150.49329018102594,
    "VALUE2": "75.28292350135503",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T19:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1200"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 20:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "20",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 132.90939839406852,
    "VALUE2": "67.6641419034086",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T19:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1220"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 20:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "20",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 80.28565707426297,
    "VALUE2": "54.21677488141204",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T19:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1240"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 21:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "21",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 86.51819145398362,
    "VALUE2": "76.47547776446376",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T20:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1260"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 21:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "21",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 100.58643623741963,
    "VALUE2": "54.02216986378453",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T20:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1280"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 21:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "21",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 109.88077988150214,
    "VALUE2": "88.83099789311015",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T20:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1300"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 22:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "22",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 133.64148337171653,
    "VALUE2": "86.82795237554191",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T21:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1320"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 22:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "22",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 141.1790901060669,
    "VALUE2": "55.91956277329068",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T21:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1340"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 22:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "22",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 106.49414930906852,
    "VALUE2": "74.54271614590431",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T21:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1360"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 23:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "23",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 140.44553457410672,
    "VALUE2": "78.3447955131424",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T22:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1380"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 23:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "23",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 102.26703222395386,
    "VALUE2": "54.51054689408265",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T22:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1400"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 23:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "23",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 138.07031707200693,
    "VALUE2": "80.52691368274375",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T22:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "1420"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 00:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "0",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 131.8403388480975,
    "VALUE2": "163.40706930229612",
    "TIME": "1899-12-31T23:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "0"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 00:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "0",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 128.66143180880016,
    "VALUE2": "182.4166850946821",
    "TIME": "1899-12-31T23:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "20"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 00:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "0",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 157.9838672230082,
    "VALUE2": "177.12826879097582",
    "TIME": "1899-12-31T23:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "40"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 01:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "1",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 154.74491894762372,
    "VALUE2": "177.0205615343229",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "60"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 01:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "1",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 145.17425322202857,
    "VALUE2": "170.28572211898427",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T00:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "80"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 01:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "1",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 86.33692934233684,
    "VALUE2": "161.306233500133",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T00:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "100"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 02:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "2",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 157.70472270832147,
    "VALUE2": "175.57007397898963",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T01:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "120"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 02:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "2",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 92.04378773072384,
    "VALUE2": "152.75885569609832",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T01:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "140"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 02:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "2",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 94.91482763887927,
    "VALUE2": "164.34713115356462",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T01:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "160"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 03:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "3",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 150.58752716935703,
    "VALUE2": "152.5739950034875",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T02:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "180"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 03:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "3",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 147.64763286003245,
    "VALUE2": "181.7346317353725",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T02:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "200"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 03:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "3",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 152.00311766772614,
    "VALUE2": "169.43438782829136",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T02:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "220"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 04:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "4",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 90.67568616871652,
    "VALUE2": "165.94364405219295",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T03:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "240"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 04:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "4",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 127.6260776280666,
    "VALUE2": "154.41327889693227",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T03:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "260"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 04:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "4",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 88.35193693321801,
    "VALUE2": "86.7514997924824",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T03:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "280"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 05:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "5",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 99.44723697225662,
    "VALUE2": "61.81705113015809",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T04:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "300"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 05:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "5",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 153.28490595395064,
    "VALUE2": "70.71671056760238",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T04:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "320"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 05:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "5",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 139.53124376248127,
    "VALUE2": "86.96902617467873",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T04:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "340"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 06:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "6",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 144.5960580946409,
    "VALUE2": "53.46091762212306",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T05:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "360"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 06:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "6",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 110.0561197803852,
    "VALUE2": "73.32550566412914",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T05:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "380"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 06:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "6",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 151.21482961729612,
    "VALUE2": "50.85883825605632",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T05:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "400"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 07:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "7",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 127.88766918064591,
    "VALUE2": "52.45266678876003",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T06:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "420"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 07:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "7",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 148.72830141013,
    "VALUE2": "60.496196118302194",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T06:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "440"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 07:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "7",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 83.62908148257569,
    "VALUE2": "86.54612924908034",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T06:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "460"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 08:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "8",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 113.49475177931872,
    "VALUE2": "59.15439348393694",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T07:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "480"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 08:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "8",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 139.37377082538475,
    "VALUE2": "86.1347823168292",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T07:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "500"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 08:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "8",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 104.5216263376223,
    "VALUE2": "86.92624219265554",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T07:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "520"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 09:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "9",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 152.55680056900144,
    "VALUE2": "60.938994790632144",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T08:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "540"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 09:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "9",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 140.38896796205978,
    "VALUE2": "56.19504976107255",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T08:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "560"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 09:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "9",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 135.79579769996857,
    "VALUE2": "62.50941443441722",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T08:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "580"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 10:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "10",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 139.82904911416367,
    "VALUE2": "55.70678841865249",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T09:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "600"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 10:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "10",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 91.69787531743796,
    "VALUE2": "60.136426910820354",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T09:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "620"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 10:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "10",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 96.81085932421924,
    "VALUE2": "80.24824051838286",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T09:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "640"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 11:00:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "11",
    "MINUTE": "0",
    "VALUE1": 100.11254271252508,
    "VALUE2": "60.56291710797137",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T10:00:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "660"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 11:20:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "11",
    "MINUTE": "20",
    "VALUE1": 92.56760281588778,
    "VALUE2": "71.09234847495347",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T10:20:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "680"
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01 11:40:00",
    "ID": "1",
    "HOUR": "11",
    "MINUTE": "40",
    "VALUE1": 100.3186503333999,
    "VALUE2": "72.55516506446128",
    "TIME": "1900-01-01T10:40:00.000Z",
    "INSPECTION": 1,
    "seconds": "700"
  }
]

// Set up the SVG container
const svgWidth = 600;
const svgHeight = 400;
const margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 50 };
const chartWidth = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
const chartHeight = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight);

const chart = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);
  
  

// Parse the date string and extract only the time as hours and minutes
    const parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ")

      // Convert data types
      data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.TIME = parseTime(d.TIME);
        d.VALUE1 = +d.VALUE1;
        d.INSPECTION = +d.INSPECTION;
      });
      data.sort((a,b)=>a.TIME-b.TIME)
      let visit1 = data.filter(d => d.INSPECTION === 1);
      // console.log(visit1)
      // Set up scales
      const xScale = d3
        .scaleTime()
         .domain([parseTime("1900-01-01T12:00:00.000Z"), parseTime("1900-01-01T23:59:00.000Z")])
        .range([0, chartWidth]);

      const yScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 180])
        .range([chartHeight, 0]);

      // Set up axes
      const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
        .ticks(d3.timeHour.every(1)) // Display tick labels every 1 hour
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M"));

      const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

      // Add axes to the chart
      chart
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "x-axis")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${chartHeight})`)
        .call(xAxis);

      chart.append("g").attr("class", "y-axis").call(yAxis);

      // Define the line function
      const line = d3
        .line()
        .x((d) => xScale(d.TIME))
        .y((d) => yScale(d.VALUE1));

      // Draw the line chart
      chart
        .append("path")
        .datum(visit1)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>D3 CSV Example</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* LINE CHART */
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ed3700;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>D3 CSV Example</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I would like to have x-axis that starts from 12:00, goes to 00:00, and end at 11:59. How can I achieve this? Please see What I expect part in my post.

Comment: Your data span from '1899-12-31T23:00:00.000Z' to '1900-01-01T22:30:39.000Z'. Put 2 value in your xScale domain array, `.domain([parseTime("1900-01-01T12:00:00.000Z"), parseTime("1900-01-02T23:59:00.000Z")])` with whatever dates you want to display, first value is lower bound second value is higher bound.

Comment: no, my data is from the same day,month, and year. I only customly ordered my data. I think somehow I need to manipulate my data so that x-axis can start from 12:00, goes to 00:00, and end at 11:59.

Comment: on data you provided entry n°43 time is  "TIME": "1899-12-31T23:00:00.000Z"

Comment: thanks for pointing out that. something is wrong with `const parseTime` I will check it